# ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'delete'

Tags: javascript, html5

Мне нужно сделать функцию, которая бы удаляла из верстки элементы корзины. Для этого пишу такой код:

```
{% extends 'main_page/main_page.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block css %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/basket.css' %}"/>

{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="image">изображение</td>
      <td class="text">название на латинском</td>
      <td class="text">цена на единицу</td>
      <td class="text">количество</td>
      <td class="text">сумма</td>
      <td class="text">удалить</td>
    </tr>
    {% for i, basket_element in basket_elements %}
      <tr id="table_row{{i}}">
        <td class="image">
          <img src="/{{ basket_element.image.url }}/" alt="картинка не работает" width="170" height="200">
        </td>
        <td class="text">{{ basket_element.latin_name }}</td>
        <td class="text">{{ basket_element.price }} руб</td>
        <td class="text">
            <input name="quantity" class="quantity{{ i }}" id="quantity{{ i }}" type="text" value="1">
            <button class="button{{ i }}" id="button{{ i }}" onclick="reprice({{ i }}, {{ basket_element.price }})" type="submit">
              <img src="{% static 'img/reload.png' %}" alt="reload">
            </button>
        </td>
        <td class="text-{{ i }}" id="end-price{{ i }}">{{ basket_element.price }}</td>
        <td class="text">
          <button id="delete{{ i }}" onclick="delete({{ i }})" type="submit">удалить</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
    <script>
      function reprice(i, price_of_element){
        let button = document.getElementById('button'+i);
        let input = document.getElementById("quantity"+i);
        let str;
        if (input != null) {
            str = input.value;
            console.log(str);
            var price = str * price_of_element;
        }
        else {
            price = price_of_element;
        }
        let end = document.getElementById("end-price"+i);
        console.log(price);
        console.log(end);
        end.innerHTML = price;
        return price;
      }
      function delete(i){
        let element = document.getElementById("table_row"+i);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
      };
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) – это оператор, поэтому его нельзя использовать в качестве имени функции в ее определении.

В данном случае стоит просто переименовать функцию, например в `deleteItem`

Comment: да, спасибо. Я правда уже смог решить данную проблему как раз поменяв имя функции